# AngularJS access to $first of ngRepeat parent in a nested ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get access to $first of a ngRepeat parent from within a nested ngRepeat. Is there a way to alias or access $first for use within nested ngRepeat?  I've tried $parent.$first, but it doesn't appear to work.  Outputting to screen by interpolation indicates it has the same value as the $first of the nested child.

```
$parent.$first // same value as nested child
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeesh, you have to go up two-levels to access the ngRepeat parent directive:

```
$parent.$parent.$first
```

Comment: You must have something extra there because it seems to work correctly here - http://plnkr.co/edit/RSXw8L81dmBnH3WHg0Vo?p=preview

Comment: Ah @Dylan, thanks you're right there is an attribute directive on the input I had skimmed over and missed.