# AngularJS - How to get two indexes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having two ng-repeat for child and parent divs as follows

```
<div ng-repeat="stage in stages">
  <div ng-repeat="step in steps">
    <button ng-click="clickedStageAndStep($index)">
  </div>
</div>

$scope.clickedStageAndStep = function(index) {
  console.log("Step Index: " + index)
};
```

I wanna get child and parent indexes. How can I fetch?

Comment: To access the index of the parent you have to go two steps up by writing `$parent.$parent.$index` See here: [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875437/angularjs-access-to-first-of-ngrepeat-parent-in-a-nested-ngrepeat ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing 2 $index values within nested ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256600/passing-2-index-values-within-nested-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `$parent.$index`

Each `ng-repeat` has its own scope and `$index` refers to innermost scope of `ng-repeat`

```js
$scope.clickedStageAndStep = function(parent, child) {
  console.log("Step Index: " + child);
};
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="stage in stages">
  <div ng-repeat="step in steps">
    <button ng-click="clickedStageAndStep($parent.$index,$index)"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note:* `</button>` tag is not closed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$parent.$index`

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="stage in stages">
    <div ng-repeat="step in stage.steps">
      <span>Index: {{$index}}. ParentIndex:{{$parent.$index}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.stages = [{
    steps: ['1', '2', '3']
  }, {
    steps: ['4', '5']
  },
  {steps:['6','7','8']}];
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1wyvfpob/).

Answer (score 3):

Use $index and $parent.$index to get child and parent indexes.

```
 <div ng-repeat="stage in stages">
      <div ng-repeat="step in steps">
        <button ng-click="clickedStageAndStep($parent.$index,$index)">
      </div>
    </div>

    $scope.clickedStageAndStep = function(stageIndex,stepIndex) {
      console.log("Stage Index: " + stageIndex + "And Step Index: " + stepIndex);
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a variable that for parent index

```
    <div ng-repeat="stage in stages" ng-init="stageNumber = $index">
      <div ng-repeat="step in steps">
          <button ng-click="clickedStageAndStep($index, $parent.$index)" >YourButton </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    $scope.clickedStageAndStep = function(stageIndex,stepIndex) {
      console.log("Step Index: " + stepIndex + "And StageIndex: " + stageIndex)
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<div ng-init="parentIndex = $index"> </div>
```

Comment: correct! but it's just doesn't answer the question and i guess you missed what OP is doing?

Comment: yeah, i admit i forgot about op. Too much coffee today push me to answer that question :) above answer is better